# How to use a shiny app inside rmarkdown file?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

How can i add a shiny app inside the rmarkdown file? I have a file named app.r (contains the shiny app) and another file rep.rmd. i saw something like

```
shinyAppDir(
  system.file("app.R", package = "shiny"),
  options = list(
    width = "100%", height = 550
  )
)
```

To use the shinyapp inside my rmarkdown file.
But it shows this error in console `could not find function "shinyAppDir"`
How can i use my shiny app inside the rmarkdown file?

**EDIT:**

It's not really a solution as this is more like a workaround, but what i did is to actually put all my files (app.R and report.rmd) into the same folder with the library shiny, and now it detects it. Still, one problem would be that if you have many libraries included in your `app.r` , it might collapse and terminate R session.

Comment: Do you have `library(shiny)` somewhere in your Rmd file?

Comment: I had it but it was misplaced. sorry about that. Now when i use `shinyAppDir(system.file("D:/myfolder/))` -> Thats the folder where i have my shiny app -> it shows this error: `Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
  path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

Comment: Is the app file in the same directory as the Rmd file?

Comment: Yes, it is. I also tried with `shinyAppFile(system.file("app.R", package='shiny'))`, but the same error. Also, in console, if i just go `normalizePath("app.R")` it works and it shows me `D:\\myfolder\\app.R`

Comment: Though if i type `system.file('D:\\myfolder\\app.R')` in console it just returns an empty string